# How sensitive are laptop barrel jack sizes?

Tags: cables, plug

In particular, is a barrel jack described as 1.35mm x 3.5mm likely to work with a socket made for a 1.3mm x 3.4mm jack?

Comment: retention force and reliability matters and so does matching diameter . Where did you come up with 3.4mm ? the plug?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 So 0.05mm and 0.1mm discrepancy are likely to be a problem?

Comment: yes I would think so, but show specs for plug and jack to avoid error

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 re "Where did you come up with 3.4mm?": it's a bit circuitious. The machine is a pinebookpro. The official PBP replacement cable is described as "Type H". The only precise information I found on Type H jacks via an internet search was an Amazon product page listing a Type H jack with measurements 1.3mm x 3.4mm. The replacement cable I was considering buying gives its measurements as 1.35mm x 3.5mm.

Comment: Buy it, plug it in.  If it works and doesn't get warm to the touch, you're good.

Comment: Search for type ‘E’ barrel jacks instead https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking manufacturing tolerances mean that there is some play between stated sizes and actual product. This applies in both directions too big and too small. When you vary too much from the nominal sizing then insertion and contact will be affected. Too loose or tight. Intermittent connections etc.

Specifically your outer diameter is larger which means it may not fit in the hole, or if it does it may stretch out the outer contact. Probably fine enough. Your inner diameter is also larger. As this one tends to be a press fit sizing it may not even touch the inside unless jammed to a side. If you jiggle it it will break and make contact.

Or it may be close enough to work. You can test to see. As mentioned in comments, if it gets too hot it may have a poor contact and thus high resistance. This is more important for high current applications. Heat is bad.

Answer (score 2):

[Type E is obscure but available](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/cui-devices/PJ-075DH-SMT-TR/3661520)